# Import all files from a folder on python

Tags: python, python-import

I have a folder with a few python files:

```
modules
|--> __init__.py
|--> car.py
|--> plane.py
|--> ship.py
|--> etc...
```

Each of this files consists on this:

car.py

```
NAME = "car_name"
def mainloop(*args):
    ...
    return whatever
```

plane.py

```
NAME = "some_different_name"
def mainloop(*args):
    ...
    return whatever
```

and so on...

I want to import them dynamically from my parent dir as a dict like this:

```
from modules import modules
print(modules)
{
    "car_name": <function mainloop at ...>,    
    "some_different_name": <function mainloop at ...>,
    etc..
}
```

I don't know how many files will be on the folder or the filenames.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`modules.py`:

```
import os, importlib
fs = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.py')]
modules = {m.NAME: m.mainloop for m in map(importlib.import_module, fs)
               if hasattr(m, 'mainloop')}
```

Comment: I think his file structure suggests you should have `os.listdir('./modules')` in `fs`, since he is running the script on the parent directory

Comment: Yep, it worked changing `os.listdir('./modules')` Thanks guys

Comment: I get an error complaining 'No module named x' on this line: map(importlib.import_module, fs)

Comment: Can you explain the code please, especially the last line  :(